# Guaranteed Application pods is in Pending state when dummy guaranteed pods are Running

Tags: kubernetes

In my project, I need to test if Guaranteed Application pods should evict any dummy application pods which are running. How do I achieve that application pods always have the highest priority?

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by the [P....](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309601/p) is very good and useful. By [Pod Priority and Preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/) you can achieve what you are up to.

However, apart from that, you can use dedicated solutions, for example in the clouds. Look at the [Google cloud example](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/get-the-most-out-of-google-kubernetes-engine-with-priority-and-preemption):

> Before priority and preemption, Kubernetes pods were scheduled purely on a first-come-first-served basis, and ran to completion (or forever, in the case of pods created by something like a Deployment or StatefulSet). This meant less important workloads could block more important, later-arriving, workloads from running—not the desired effect. Priority and preemption solves this problem.
>
> Priority and preemption is valuable in a number of scenarios. For example, imagine you want to cap autoscaling to a maximum cluster size to control costs, or you have clusters that you can’t grow in real-time (e.g., because they are on-premises and you need to buy and install additional hardware). Or you have high-priority cloud workloads that need to scale up faster than the cluster autoscaler can add nodes. In short, priority and preemption lead to better resource utilization, lower costs and better service levels for critical applications.

Additional guides for other clouds:

- [IBM cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-pod_priority)
- [AWS cloud](https://www.eksworkshop.com/intermediate/201_resource_management/pod-priority/)
- [Azure cloud](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-advanced-scheduler)
- [RedHat Openshift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-priority.html)

See also [this useful tutorial](https://mohaamer5.medium.com/kubernetes-pod-priority-and-preemption-943c58aee07d).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [kind: PriorityClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/#pod-priority) to give your application a higher priority then normal pods.

Answer (score 0):

The eviction is based on the priority of the Pod, QoS, and the actual usage of the Pod. If the Pod belongs to a higher priority pod, its creation will preempt the bestEffort, followed by burstable followed by guaranteed pods.

For example: In my cluster, I have the following [priority classes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/#pod-priority):

```
kubectl get priorityclasses.scheduling.k8s.io 
NAME                      VALUE        GLOBAL-DEFAULT   AGE
k8s-cluster-critical      1000000000   false            11d
system-cluster-critical   2000000000   false            11d
system-node-critical      2000001000   false            11d
```

For the sake of example, I used the `system-cluster-critical` class. Do not do this, have your priority class. The following Pod would lead to the eviction of other pods.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: guaranteed
spec:
  nodeName: kube-worker-1
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: nginx
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 1000m
        memory: 300Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 1000m
        memory: 300Mi
```

In the description of the other pods, you would see the following:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason      Age    From     Message
  ----     ------      ----   ----     -------
  Normal   Pulling     3m19s  kubelet  Pulling image "nginx"
  Normal   Pulled      3m19s  kubelet  Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 495.693296ms
  Normal   Created     3m19s  kubelet  Created container app
  Normal   Started     3m19s  kubelet  Started container app
  Warning  Preempting  18s    kubelet  Preempted in order to admit critical Pod
  Normal   Killing     18s    kubelet  Stopping container app
```

Note that if in your cluster there is no priority class with global default then the priority of the pods without any priority class would be zero(minimum priority). So based on the type of application you should have multiple priority classes created and used.